# Post-Api Deployment in APIGateway not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I been following this tutorial to create an Post and GET api as proxy to write to my dynamo DB. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-api-gateway-as-a-proxy-for-dynamodb/

I got the post api working internally however, when I deploy it live, the GET works perfectly, however, the post does not write to the DB.

**Table Name: License Plate**
[Response of the Post request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWE5Y.png)

```
the URI is Iteration3/LicensePlateNumber/{LicensePlateNumber}
```

and this is how I am passing the values.

```
/Iteration3/LicensePlateNumber/{"Actual_License_PlateNumber" :"testfrombrowser}
```

but nothing is being inputted to dyanmo db.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have not given closing " with the value `testfrombrowser`. See the example with the values you passed.

```
/Iteration3/LicensePlateNumber/{"Actual_License_PlateNumber" :"testfrombrowser}
```

It should be:

```
/Iteration3/LicensePlateNumber/{"Actual_License_PlateNumber" :"testfrombrowser"}
```

May be that is a typo mistake.
Check below things.

- Turn on log/tracing from stage editor and see cloudwatch logs for on
  apigateway execution.
- Make sure that while defining AWS Proxy integration, execution Role
  (IAM role) mentioned for PutItem action has sufficient permissions on
  DynamoDb.
- Also make sure that you are executing APIgateway POST method
  correctly.

See an example curl call.

```
curl -X POST -H "x-api-key: theKey" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"Actual_License_PlateNumber":"testfrombrowser"}' https://[api--id].execute-api.[region].amazonaws.com
```